# Where can one get real (health) actuarial/insurance probability data/distributions?

Tags: dataset, relative-risk

I'm researching some problems in the health/medical insurance sector and would like to use actual probability distributions (or current data) for doing some sort of risk analysis using simple simulations and the like, to see how different types of policies stack up against different people's perception of risk.

I guess the only type of data I'd need IMO is the probability of fatality for various types of injuries (assuming the 'types' are quite granular). For example: 0.05% chance of a fatal injury, 25% chance of fracture etc.,

Basically some real data on which I can base my analysis to gauge the risk attitudes of buyers of the policy.

Any ideas/pointers would be greatly appreciated. If the data is country specific I'm preferably targeting North America, South America and Europe.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at these links.

http://www.cdc.gov/nchs/nvss/mortality_tables.htm

http://www.cdc.gov/nchs/products/life_tables.htm

These links have all kinds of data, including life expectancy, causes of death of people etc. etc. for USA.